# How to debug an XPCOM error from within Javascript

Tags: firefox-addon, xpcom

On disabling and re-enabling my addon, I get the error below (I have one simple XPCOM component) -- how might one go about debugging something like this?

> Call to xpconnect wrapped JSObject produced this error:  *
>   [Exception... "'[JavaScript Error: "can't access dead object" {file:
>   "resource://gre/modules/XPIProvider.jsm ->
>   jar:file:///Users/me/code/testprof/extensions/ext@myext.org.xpi!/bootstrap.js
>   -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/chrome.js" line: 36}]' when
>   calling method: [nsIObserver::observe]"  nsresult: "0x80570021
>   (NS_ERROR_XPC_JAVASCRIPT_ERROR_WITH_DETAILS)"  location: "JS frame ::
>   resource://gre/modules/XPIProvider.jsm ->
>   jar:file:///Users/me/code/testprof/extensions/ext@myext.org.xpi!/bootstrap.js
>   -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/window.js ::  ::
>   line 43"  data: yes]

Answer (score 0):

cant access dead object means, you had set like a global variable to = window. now that window is no longer there.

check your observer, it might be holding a variable with reference to some window or document object.

the way you got that message is the only way to debug, using the browser console (Ctrl+Shift+J) but make sure you have developer preferences set up:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Development_preferences

Comment: Doesn't appear to have any global reference (there is also no noticeable error). Just the error messages in the console. Is there really no other way to debug this more systematically?